# Is this a valid transformation of a expression?

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

I need to check if this function is continuous:

$$f(x)= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{4+x^{6n}}$$

So I did this:

$$f(x)= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{4+x^{6n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}(4+x^{6n})^{1/n} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(x^{6n}\cdot \left(\frac{4}{x^{6n}}+ 1 \right) \right)^{1/n}$$

$$f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}x^6 \cdot \left(\frac 4 {x^{6n}}+ 1\right)^{1/n} = x^6$$

Is this valid? Can I now just check the continuity of:

$$f(x) = x^6$$

Comment: It's a sequence of functions.

Comment: are you guaranteed $x>1$?

Comment: @AbdallahHammam I don't understand sorry.

Comment: @KitterCatter No.

Comment: if $x<1$ does $(\frac{4}{x^{6n}}+1)$ approach 1 for large n?

Comment: @KitterCatter I got it. I forgot I have to check that when I have $x^n$ in my expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Your function $f$ is defined by

$f(x)=1$ if $|x|\leq 1$  and

$f(x)=x^6$ if $|x|>1$.

so, it is continuous at $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Ah yes, I have to use the results I know for $\lim_{n\to\infty} q^n$, becuse I have $x^n$ in my expression right?

Answer (score 1):

When you did the $$\lim_{n\to\infty}({4+x^{6n})^{1/n}} =\lim_{n\to\infty}(x^{6n}\cdot({\frac{4}{x^{6n}}+ 1))^{1/n}}$$
step, you introduced a discontinuity at $f(0)$, due to the $\frac4{x^{6n}}$ which is a div$/0$ error that was not accounted for. See if you can find a different way around this issue.